# Machine.Migrations mature enough to be used?

Tags: .net, database

Ok thanks for the 1st guy I found the code.

Machine.Migrations: I mean, the data schema/data migration framework.

I mean, the one mentioned here:
http://blog.eleutian.com/2008/04/25/AFirstLookAtMachineMigrations.aspx

Ok so somebody had used it? I think I would like to have such framework in my project (I have been using rails, such framework helps a lot on making migration more systematic)

Comment: Would you remove "I seem..." from the title and add it to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an experimental library authored by the blog author.

See http://blog.eleutian.com/Default.aspx#a2e4f933f-e00c-445e-ab64-17bf9a64d96f

There is a link at the bottom of that post.

Comment: Yeah you are right :) A bit too small to note. Actually I did browse the repository once, but didnt notice its inside

Answer (score 0):

I've just publish a new migrations library called Mig#. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp

It should be mature enough as we are using it at my workplace for productive code.

Mig# currently offers support for SQL Server 2005/2008/CE 4, Oracle, and Teradata. On top of that, you get a nifty validation framework and more (see https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp/wiki/Feature-Overview).